# Order changed after distinct() : RethinkDb Javascript

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, nosql

I am working with the Reql, the problem i am facing is that i need to filter the same plucked values in correct order.

After pluck and distinct() apply, value are correct but not in correct order, their order lost.

Sample Query

```
r.db('DB').table("heroes").orderBy('createdAt')
 .pluck({'loc':['coordinates']})
  .distinct()
```

Can anyone help me to modify the query, so that it return data in correct order.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for another workaround i posted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893124/remove-duplicate-items-from-array-of-nested-objects-and-retain-their-order-jav) (thanks to @trincot) to get work done in javascript instead to handle duplicate array of lat longs, by duplicating solution of this sample array. Getting distinct result and the order is maintained.

```
var array = [  
    { person: { amount: [1,1] } },
    { person: { amount: [1,1] } }, 
    { person: { amount: [2,1] } },
    { person: { amount: [1,2] } },
    { person: { amount: [1,2] } }
];

var result = [...new Map(array.map( o => [JSON.stringify(o), o])).values()];

console.log(result);
```

In case of anyone who might get help.Cheers.