# Remove duplicate items from array of nested objects and retain their order : javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to remove the duplicate items from an array without harming their order.
Please Consider this array of data

```
var array = [  { person: { amount: [1,1] } },
{ person: { amount: [1,1] } }, 
{ person: { amount: [2,1] } },
{ person: { amount: [1,2] } },
{ person: { amount: [1,2] } }];
```

I understand that it can be done by using new Set([iterable]) but can't work with this array. If anyone have an idea, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add the wanted result. what means *duplicate*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: You can clearly try something before posting this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: i thinks this question is different, i needed to maintain the order, and if you look at it you'll see, before posting possible duplicate links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert the elements to JSON and use those as keys for a Map, and then convert that back to an array (now with update suggested by Nina Scholz):

```js
var array = [  
    { person: { amount: [1,1] } },
    { person: { amount: [1,1] } }, 
    { person: { amount: [2,1] } },
    { person: { amount: [1,2] } },
    { person: { amount: [1,2] } }
];

var result = [...new Map(array.map( o => [JSON.stringify(o), o])).values()];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A Map maintains the order in which items are added to it, so the original order is not altered by this process.

You could do it also with an intermediate Set instead of a Map, but then you need to reconstruct the objects from JSON, which limits the functionality when you have some non-key properties in your objects that are not JSON compatible (like functions):

```
var result = Array.from(new Set(array.map( o => JSON.stringify(o))), s => JSON.parse(s));
```

Comment: @trincot that is the brilliant solution ever, thanks for the help

Comment: you could omit the mapFn and use `result = [...(new Map(array.map(o => [JSON.stringify(o), o]))).values()]`

Comment: Thanks, @NinaScholz, your insights are valuable, as always! I shamelessly took that into my answer -- omitting one pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Double usage of `Array#map`, but allows you to avoid `Object.values()` which is supported only by Chrome and Firefox.

```js
var arr = [  
    { person: { amount: [1,1] } },
    { person: { amount: [1,1] } }, 
    { person: { amount: [2,1] } },
    { person: { amount: [1,2] } },
    { person: { amount: [1,2] } }
], res = [...new Set(arr.map(v => JSON.stringify(v)))].map(v => JSON.parse(v));
   
   console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```